# Use regex to enforce cell validation?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Using Excel 2010.  I want to only allow values in a cell that fit a given regex pattern.  So I created a UDF module as follows:

```
Public re as RegExp

Public Function isValidRegex(rng As Range, pattern As String) As Boolean

If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = New RegExp
End If

re.pattern = pattern

isValidRegex = re.Test(rng.value)

End Function
```

I created a named range called THIS_CELL, so that the current cell can be passed to `isValidRegex()`, as follows:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

I set a custom validation for the cell, using this formula:

```
=isValidRegex(THIS_CELL,"(my|regex)patt[ern]")
```

This generated the following error:

```
A named range you specified cannot be found.
```

According to [this article](http://www.helpinfo.com/index.jsp?k2dockey=1021024569555613607&formwassubmitted=true), UDFs cannot be used in Custom validation formulas.  The solution suggested in the article (putting the formula in another cell, making that cell into a named range, and referencing that cell in the Custom formula) won't work, because I need to be able to pass THIS_CELL as an argument to the function.

I also tried creating a named range called **isValidRegexPattern**, defining it as `=isValidRegex(THIS_CELL,"(my|regex)patt[ern]")`, and setting the Custom formula to `=isValidRegexPattern`, but this didn't work either; putting a breakpoint in `isValidRegex()` showed that the function wasn't even being called.

So, how can I use a UDF for cell validation?

Comment: Why don't you use the Change event to validate the entry?

Comment: @brettdj, attempting to enter invalid data should result in restoration of whatever was in the cell before the attempted change.  Which AFAIK is impossible using worksheet events; say I copy A1:A5 and paste into B1.  `Worksheet_SelectionChange` will catch the pre-change value of B1, but not B2:B5, and because it's a VBA call, Undo won't retrieve the previous values.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: you should use the `Worksheet_Change` event that would work for you

Comment: Also do you really need to use RegEx, is your pattern so complicated that you can't use the `Like` operator

Comment: @jeanno, `Worksheet_Change` doesn't capture the pre-change state of the cell, as I said in my comment to brettdj.  As for RegEx complexity, there are several patterns that involve repeated capturing groups, e.g. "^(\d{3}(,|$))+".  These are somewhat complicated to express with `Like`, and would probably each require their own VBA string-processing algorithm if we don't use Regex.

Comment: Any special reason you refrain from using validation options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be reluctant to move over to a `WorksheetChange` event macro because you believe it does not *'capture the pre-change state of the cell'*. That may be correct in the strictest definition but that doesn't mean you cannot capture the changed state, undo the change, determine whether the change is valid and only re-apply the change if it meets criteria.

I'm not going to produce a full regex validating function. This simply tests if the number typed into column E is less than zero or blank. If not then the cell reverts to its prechange state.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(5)) Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Dim vNEW As Variant
            vNEW = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            If bIs_It_Valid(vNEW) Then
                Target = vNEW
            Else
                ' put stuff like idiot warnings here
            End If
        End If
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Function bIs_It_Valid(val As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(val) Then _
        bIs_It_Valid = CBool(val < 0)
    Debug.Print bIs_It_Valid
End Function
```

That `Worksheet_Change` could probably be adjusted to work on a range of cells if pasting a number of values is important.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) variable with the `Worksheet_Change` event to keep a snapshot of the prior values

The code below tracks the values in `A1:A10` and uses a `Regexp` like yours to reject any non-numeric entries

The example below tries top copy and paste `B1:B10` over `A1:A10`, only `A6`and `A8` are allowed as they are numeric

*to set the range initially change a cell outside the range of interest to trigger  `If IsEmpty(X) Then X = [a1:a10].Value2`*

[image]

[image]

*change event*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Static X As Variant
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

If IsEmpty(X) Then X = [a1:a10].Value2

Set rng2 = Intersect([a1:a10], Target)
If rng2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng3 In rng2
    If Not isValidRegex(rng3, "\d+") Then rng3.Value = X(rng3.Row, 1)
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

X = [a1:a10].Value2

End Sub
```

*regexp*

```
Function isValidRegex(rng As Range, pattern As String) As Boolean
Dim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
re.pattern = pattern
isValidRegex = re.Test(rng.Value)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here's how I accomplished this without using the `Worksheet_Change` event

Define a Public REGEX Function in a new Module

```vb
'Public REGEX Formula
Public Function REGEX(pattern As String, cel As Range) As Boolean
    Dim re As New RegExp
    re.pattern = pattern
    REGEX = re.Test(cel.Value)
End Function
```

I added this Sub to a module I named `Validations`. This Sub requires not only the range to validate and the regular expression pattern, but also another range to apply the REGEX formula to. The actual validation applied actually only checks that separate cell for a `True` or `False` value. This is a simplified version that assumes the `validationColumn` is an entire column.

```vb
'Validations Module
Sub regexValidation(cells As Range, pattern As String, validationColumn As Range, defaultValue As String)
    Dim cel As Range, regexFormula As String, validationCell As Range

    cells.Value = defaultValue

    'Need to match true on default value or validation will always fail
    pattern = "(" & defaultValue & ")|(" & pattern & ")"

    For Each cel In cells
        regexFormula = "=REGEX(""" & pattern & """," & cel.address & ")"
        Set validationCell = validationColumn.cells(cel.Row, 1)
        validationCell.Formula = regexFormula
        cel.Validation.Delete
        cel.Validation.Add xlValidateCustom, Formula1:="=" & Trim(validationCell.address)
    Next cel
End Sub
```

This is how I'm calling it. In my case, this is a `UserForm` with a `TextBox` called `regexPattern` that contains the regular expression to apply.

```vb
'Form
Private Sub applyRegexValidation(cells As Range)
    Validations.regexValidation cells, regexPattern.text, validationColumn:=cells.Parent.Range("AA:AA"), defaultValue:="Required Custom"
End Sub
```